# Laravel 5.5 - remember me and custom session values issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I installed laravel 5.5 and I set some custom values in session on login

inside Auth/LoginController

```
public function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{    
    Session::put('full_name', 'Thomas');
    Session::put('age', '35');
    Session::put('place', 'UK');
    Session::save();
}
```

I set my session time out to 1 minute in .env file

```
SESSION_LIFETIME=1
```

When a user login, If he click on Remember me checkbox, a new cookie generated and remember_token inserted into USERS table.

I print the custom session values in a view file after getting them from session

```
$full_name = Session::get('full_name');
$age = Session::get('age');
$place= Session::get('place');
return view('home', compact('full_name', 'age', 'place'));
```

After 1 minute of inactivity, my session get expired, but since the user checked Remember me, he will be logged **but the values in Session get vanished**

This does not make sense!, I need the session values as long as the user is logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user got authenticated via the `remember_token` functionality, the `Auth\LoginController@authenticated` method is not called.

The best practice for this would be a global middleware that checks if the user is authenticated and if the session data is set. If it isn't set, set the data.

Your middleware function could look similar to this one:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if(!Auth::check()) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    if(Session::has('full_name') && Session::has('age') && Session::has('place')) {
        Session::put('full_name', 'Thomas');
        Session::put('age', '35');
        Session::put('place', 'UK');
        Session::save();
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: can we use a loginEvent (fire on login) instead of middleware to achieve the same?

Comment: Never tried it, but as far as i know it isn't possible

Comment: thanks, Is it possible to override the login via remember_token function? (like we override the login function)

Comment: I'm not deep enough to be 100 percent sure, but i would say that this would be very complex because you have to override very much of the `Illuminate\Auth` namespace. The remember_me functionality works through the `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware which uses the `Auth` class to check if a user is authenticated. `Auth` uses your config to find the user model which implements `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable` where the remember_me function gets their data to authenticate a user through `Auth::guard($guard)->check()`